# Remove "assign from camera" option from popup menu in cxGrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

In cxGrid,when right clicking inside a blob field with your right mouse button you get the standard popup menu :

[image]

How can I remove the "Assign from camera option" ? I know there used to be such an option but now I can not find it anywhere. DevExpress is 14.2.2.

Edit:

Here are the settings of the field in question :

[image]

And here how it looks in action:

[image]

Comment: I can agree with deciding not to up-vote, but I don't understand the decision for someone to down-vote this question. This is a decent question - not knowing the answer is no excuse for a down-vote. One should at least explain their reasoning.

Comment: Why not ask the vendor? It seems to me that they are best placed to answer.

Answer (score -1):

The popup menu is not relates to a blob field. It is releated to a `TcxImage`. So the popup menu will appear on a `TcxImage` component and on any Column in a `TcxGrid` on which you sat the `Properties`property to `Image`.

Given that the answer is more or less the same:

On a `TCxGrid`
  Find the correct Column, then goto `properties` => `PopupMenuLayout` => `MenuItems`, and here you remove the unwanted menu items. The "Assign from camera option" is called `pmiWebCam`.

Hope this answers you question.

Comment: Properties = BlobEdit , BlobEditKind=bekPict ...However I do not have the PopupMenuLayout option under properties for that field.

Comment: It seems to have this option I must change Properties to that of "Image" and not BlobEdit.

Comment: Else you'll have to make a minimum complete verifiable example. Because when I try to set the properties to BlobEdit, the popupControl is nill.

Comment: @ Jens Borrisholt - yes,that's what I was saying. If the field is defined as Properties = BlobEdit then there is no PopupMenuLayout option. It only appears when Properties = Image. So it seems the only way I can remove this "assign from camera" option is to turn the properties to image. The problem is that then I would need this picture to show in its natural height when clicked but it has no such property to automatically pop up.

Comment: Make me an example showing the problem with BlobEdit and I'll have a look

Comment: @user763539, as David already mentioned you should probably ask that on the DevExpress support center.

Comment: Or just make me an example.